# Java controlf and escape sequences

Tags: java, syntax, escaping, syntax-error, system.out

I'm trying to skip a line using an escape sequence, my code looks like

```
System.out.printf("Number of students: " + numberOfStudents "\n");
```

but I am getting an error which says "Syntax error on token ""\n"", delete this token"

I get the same error when trying

```
System.out.printf("Number of students: %c", numberOfStudents "\n");
```

This code works but I'm trying to understand what I did wrong

```
System.out.printf("Number of students: %d \n", numberOfStudents );
```

Is there a rule against using escape sequences after referencing a variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
numberOfStudents "\n"
```

isn't valid. You've got two tokens there - an identifier and a string literal - with just a space between them. That's not valid. You could use concatenation:

```
System.out.printf("Number of students: " + numberOfStudents + "\n");
```

if you want... but you can't just put the string literal at the end like that.

I would suggest that your final code is the cleanest anyway, although I'd remove the space before the line break. Another alternative would be to let `println` put the line break on for you:

```
System.out.println("Number of students: " + numberOfStudents);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot the `+` in between `numberOfStudents` and `"\n"`:

```
System.out.printf("Number of students: " + numberOfStudents + "\n");
```

There must be a `+` operator between everything you want to concatenate, just like you wouldn't say `1 + 2  3` in math.